# webpack build failing: apparent dependency mismatches, how to resolve?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, yarnpkg

I'm converting a largish project to webpack and am encountering a build error (and in fact different errors depending on how I attempt to resolve).  I'm not super skilled with webpack yet and would love some help with what the typical solution is to such problems.

There seems to be a conflict between some dependencies:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.42",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.42",
"backbone.radio": "2.0.0",
```

Webpack complains: `Cannot find module 'babel-preset-es2015'`.  Looks like backbone.radio has a .babelrc file with `"presets": ["es2015"]` which babel seems to be trying to honor, even though it's a dependency, but it lists babel-preset-env as a devDependency so it's not found.

Ok, so I try to install babel-preset-es2015@6.3.13 (the same one backbone.radio referenced) explicitly as a top-level dependency so it can be found.  Then it finds it but webpack (or really babel) complains: `Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.`

Fine, so I attempt to install a newer version of the preset that's compatible with babel 7, and *hopefully* is compatible with backbone.radio.  It seems the name has changed so I install @babel/preset-es2015@7.0.0-beta.42.  Of course the name doesn't match so I add a webpack alias but that doesn't work and it still can't be found; I suppose babel doesn't load the preset dependency using babel and instead does it itself.

So now I'm stuck.  What do people usually do to resolve these sorts of problems?  Other potential ideas which I haven't determined are possible:

- tell babel (somehow?) to alias babel-preset-es2015 to @babel/preset-es2015?
- configure yarn (somehow?) to omit/remove backbone.radio's .babelrc file (the problem goes away entirely if that file is gone, but I can't just manually delete it from node_modules all the time of course)

Comment: Do you actually want to run Babel on this backbone module anyway? Usually it is best to only run Babel on your own code, so we suggest `exclude: /node_modules/` as part of the babel-loader config.

Comment: Also is there a reason you're using Babel's unstable beta? Unless there's some specific feature you want, you're less likely to hit issues if you use the stable 6.x release.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I hadn't thought of excluding backbone.radio from babel transpiling.  Is it advisable to exclude all of node_modules?  I assume plenty of modules export their source files rather than transpiled files, no?

Also, it's possible we can revert out of the unstable beta, but I expect I'd have the same problem once it's out of beta.  I assume the behavior of reading babelrc for dependencies is expected and not a bug.

Comment: It really depends on what dependencies you load and what their individual target versions are. Compiling all of node_modules indiscriminately will make your upfront build times much higher. That said, if you do want to compile node_modules, Babel's beta does make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling things in `node_modules` wasn't really a thing during Babel 6's original lifetime, so it can be painful. Up until recently, we explicitly recommended that users set `exclude: /node_modules/` in their `babel-loader` config because it was, and still is, a little dangerous to run Babel on arbitrary third-party code.

For your specific issue, you have two options:

1. Use `exclude: /node_modules/` so that Babel only processes your own code.
2. Upgrade to `beta.46`, because we've now added first-class support for the concept of Node's packages, which we didn't have before. Babel >= beta.45 will only search for `.babelrc` files in the "root" package.

I'll also add that if your Babel config is in a `.babelrc` right now, that will not affect things in `node_modules`, so if your intention is to compile third-party code, you'll want to move your config to a `babel.config.js` file in your project root, or put it in your `webpack.config.js` directly. You may also probably want to explicitly pass `sourceType: 'unambiguous'` as a Babel option.

Finally, if you're using the beta, we are absolutely still making breaking changes, so you should not use `^` in your package.json, since that will make you take the most recent version of everything, which we might have broken compared to earlier releases.

Comment: Are you saying that babel 6 wouldn't transpile anything in node_modules anyway and the ability to transpile that stuff is new in babel 7?  In any case, this sounds like the way to go.  We were previously invoking babel from gulp and were specifically omitting node_modules, but there we were explicitly listing out known transpiled code in a requirejs paths config.

Comment: Not quite, all I mean is that Babel 6 is very bad at compiling node_modules, and Babel 7 is slightly better and will likely improve more in future betas.